SFCC save selected option from "picklist" via form
I created a new attribute(preferredLanguage - Enum of String datatype) in standard 'profile' object and added it to the account creation page in storefront. However, I couldn't get the selected "picklist" value from ISML to js. I tried the below code, and there is no value catched in htmlValue. Could you please help me with this?
Please find here my code part.
js controller:

var registrationFormObj = {
            firstName: registrationForm.customer.firstname.value,
            lastName: registrationForm.customer.lastname.value,
            email: registrationForm.customer.email.value,
            preferredLanguage: registrationForm.customer.preferredLanguage.value,
            validForm: registrationForm.valid,
            form: registrationForm
        };

ISML :

<div class="form-group"
        <isif condition="${!!pdict.profileForm.customer.preferredLanguage.mandatory === true}">required</isif>">

        <label class="form-control-label" for="registration-form-preferredLanguage">
            <isprint value="${pdict.profileForm.customer.preferredLanguage.label}" encoding="htmlcontent" />
        </label>
        <div class="info-icon">
            <span><i class="fa fa-info-circle beet-color" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span class="tooltip account-tooltip d-none">Select your preferred language</span>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select form-control" id="preferredLanguage" name="preferredLanguage" >
        <isloop items="${pdict.profileForm.customer.preferredLanguage.options}" var="language">
            <option id="${language.id}" value="${language.htmlValue}" 
            <isif condition="${language.selected}">selected</isif> >${language.label}</option>
        </isloop>
        <isprint value="${pdict.profileForm.customer.preferredLanguage.attributes}" encoding="off" />
        </select>
    </div>

XML :

<field 
            formid="preferredLanguage" 
            name="preferredLanguage"
            label="label.input.preferredLanguage.profile" 
            mandatory="true"  
            missing-error="error.message.required" 
            type="string"
            binding="preferredLanguage">
            <options>
                <option optionid="" label="" value=""/>
                <option optionid="english" label="English" value="english"/>
                <option optionid="dutch" label="Dutch" value="dutch"/>
                <option optionid="spanish" label="Spanish" value="luxembourgish"/>
            </options>
        </field>

Thanks a lot!
